# How I can change the md-select text color?

Tags: angularjs, focus, angular-material

I am using angular material in my website and I want to change the `md-select` color on focus. Can someone please help me with the classes I need to use to change its color?

I tried something like this

```
md-select {
  color: blue;
}
```

Also I want to change its placeholder color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I change the md-checkbox-text color

Like this

```
<md-checkbox class="green">
   Green Checkbox
</md-checkbox>

md-checkbox.md-checked.green .md-icon {
 background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.87);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/qc2tdr0VqCtbnpc0O4Y2?p=preview

As for `ng-select`, it turns out if you inspect the DOM, the placeholder attribute is a span element. To select it, you should use the CSS descendant selector

```
.md-select span {
    color: blue;
}
```

Source

https://material.angularjs.org/0.11.2/#/CSS/checkbox

Comment: Yeah I did that for md-checkbox.. I know I must be able to figure out for this as well and its a stupid question but It would be generous if someone tells me

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I wanted to change the color of the label that goes up when an element is selected. I solved it by using the following css.

```
md-input-container label { color: #000000!important; }
```